# Ajax.actionlink object route values returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a view:

```
@model X.Models.Employee

@Ajax.ActionLink(Model.LastName[lastNameCount - 1].Value1, // <-- Text to display
   "Stuff", // <-- Action Method Name
   new
    {
     //LINE CAUSING ISSUE
      employee = Model
    },
   new AjaxOptions
    {
      bla
    },
   new
    {
     @id = "opener"
    })
```

and my controller action method looks like this

```
ActionResult Stuff(Employee employee) {
 //stuff
}
```

why is my employee returning null? can I not assign the Model to the object route values?

I've tried `Model.property` and the action method accepts the type associated with that and it works, but not with just Model

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct Overload? There's a list with all of them. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

Comment: @Guillelon yea I used the same overload to pass a route value of a different type and it worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using the wrong overload. `Employee` is a complex object so replace the 3rd parameter

```
Ajax.ActionLink(...
  Stuff",
  new
  {
    employee = Model
  },
  new AjaxOptions
  ...
```

with

```
Ajax.ActionLink(...
  Stuff",
  Model,
  new AjaxOptions
  ...
```

However `Model.LastName[lastNameCount - 1].Value1` suggests property `LastName` is a collection which wont work (route parameters cannot be created for collections and if you inspect the html you will see something like `...LastName=System.Collections.Generic.List...)`. In that case you will need to just pass the ID of the employee

```
Ajax.ActionLink(...
  "Stuff",
  new { ID = Model.ID },
  new AjaxOptions
  ....

public ActionResult Stuff(int ID) {
```

Comment: thanks for the response, is there a way to pass Model and Model.ID together?

Comment: Why do you need the two passed separately? Passing `Model` will also net you `ID`, since it's a property on `Model`.

Comment: well I don't need the ModelID, rather another id for another property, but is it possible to do this? is there an overload that I can use to pass a complex type and a property?

Comment: @AbdulAhmad, No. The helpers either accept a `RouteValueDictionary` e.g `new { ID = Model.ID, Name = Model.Name, AnotherProperty = Model.AnotherProperty, ... }` or an object. In the case of an object, reflection is used to generate a `RouteValueDictionary` from the objects properties. Its unclear just exactly what you to do and what properties you want to pass to the method but generally its better to pass just the `employee.ID` and in the method, get the `employee` from the database.